# Beginner CSS Nav Bar, Child Larger Than Parent?

Tags: html, css, layout, parent-child, navbar

I'm just learning CSS and am trying to make a very simple navigation bar, which changes colour when your mouse hovers over it.

I thought that, if I added padding to a child element, it would increase the size of its parent element. However, when I add padding to my link elements, they become bigger than the list items they are contained in, so I get this:

[nav bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UUf07.jpg)

I was wondering if anyone could anyone explain why this is? I'm so confused! Also, do you have any suggestions about how I can force the entire nav-bar to be the same height as the grey link shown in the image?

Thank you so much for your time. I really appreciate it! :)

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>
        <li><a>About</a></li>
        <li><a>Other link</a></li>
        <li><a>Another link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

And here is my css:

```
    @CHARSET "ISO-8859-1";

* {
  padding: 0; /*I read that it's a good idea to set these to 0, to avoid unexpected differences between browsers*/
  margin: 0;
  /*border-style: solid*/
}

.nav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;

  position: fixed;
  top: 0;

  display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a {
    padding: 1em 0.5em;
}

.nav a:hover{
  background-color: Grey;
}
```

Comment: happy for you that you found this solution, please read my answer as well I hope you will learn something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at this! 
This should be enough to get you started!

You added padding to a single item, but what you needed to do was add `display: block` to your `.nav a`, which is all your anchor tags of your nav.

```css
* {
  padding: 0; /*I read that it's a good idea to set these to 0, to avoid unexpected differences between browsers*/
  margin: 0;
  /*border-style: solid*/
}

.nav {
  background-color: black;
  color: white;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.nav li{
  display: inline-block;
}

.nav a {
  padding: 1em 0.5em;
  display: block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

.nav a:hover{
  background-color: grey;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <link href="styles.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">
  </head>

  <body>
    <div class="nav">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Other link</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Another link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is perfect! I don't seem to have enough reputation to upvote this right now, but hopefully I can in the future! :)

Comment: @LittleQuokka No worries about the upvote. But that's awesome! Do you have any questions about the code in the example I provided?

Comment: No, I think I understand. :) Since the anchor tags by default are "inline" instead of "block", if I give them padding, the result will be a little weird, right? After reading your post, I tried to do more research and found this site: http://maxdesign.com.au/articles/inline/, which talked a bit about padding and inline elements. I think it all makes sense now. :)

Comment: Consider a nav item as like your bedroom. Padding would be similar to adding furniture in your room. It will use space inside your room and fill it up inward, pushing text or whatever towards the center. But margin would be similar to renovation, where you take down the walls of your bedroom and expand outward to make more bedroom space ^.^

Answer (score 0):

`.nav a { padding: 1em 0.5em; }`

`1em` is what's making them become bigger. Change it to `1px` and it will do the trick for you.

https://codepen.io/julysfx/pen/weOwwr

Comment: Thank you. I think with this solution the grey part is still larger than the black part, but it's definitely less noticeable.